# Python to search and print out the whole line just like Linux grep?

Tags: python, linux, search, python-re

Let's use this as example.

```
>>> t = '''Line 1
... Line 2
... Line 3'''
>>>
```

`re.findall` only print out the specific pattern which is similar to Linux `grep -o`

```
>>> re.findall('2', t)
['2']
>>>
```

Linux grep

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo 'Line 2' | grep 2
Line 2
wolf@linux:~$
```

Linux grep -o

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo 'Line 2' | grep 2 -o
2
wolf@linux:~$
```

I know it's possible to print out the whole output, I just can't think the logic at the moment.

Expected Output in Python

```
Line 2
```

If there's better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Do what grep does. Split the input into lines, print the lines that match the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put .* around what you want to find:

```
re.findall(r'.*2.*', t)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. +1 for you. Btw, what is the meaning of r?

Comment: @Wolf - `r'...'` are raw strings. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: It means raw string.  For example, if you put a \, it means a \ character and do not interpreted as an escape character.  Out of habits, when using a regular expression, I always put r even it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
print([l for l in t.splitlines() if "2" in l])
```

Or, if you want it separated as in `grep`,

```
print('\n'.join([l for l in t.splitlines() if "2" in l]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = '''Line 1
Line 2
Line 3'''

for line in t.split('\n'):
    if(line.find("2")!=-1):
        print(line)
```

This should work for your usecase. find() is used to check if a pattern is present in a string